# tcl file listing using glob error

Tags: file, tcl, glob

I have a folder named "FILES TO COPY", contains a text file named "NEW TEXT FILE" in it.

I am wanna list the content of folder using tcl glob function.

Below is my code

```
glob -dir C:\Tcl\FILES TO COPY *
```

Error i get in tcl shell is as follows 
no files matched glob patterns "FILES TO COPY *"

Kindly help me fixing the error.

Answer (score 1):

You need some more quoting to protect the spaces, and also the backslashes are being handled by Tcl as backslashes, not directory separators:

```
glob -dir "C:/Tcl/FILES TO COPY" *
```

Comment: It can sometimes help to use `file join` to construct filenames. Admittedly it was only really necessary back on Mac Classic (where filename construction was awful to do by hand) but it's still pretty convenient since you can omit most of the slashes.